# How is this slide-up menu from the iPhone messages app implemented?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, imessage

In the Messages app on my iPhone (iOS 8.0.2), when you are composing a message and you click on the camera icon to insert an image, a "slide-up" menu appears from the bottom. It contains a few buttons, along with recently-taken pictures I could insert into my message.

What is this menu called? 
Is it available through a native class already?
How are the images nested inside the menu? 
Are there any helpful other helpful resources for implementing it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a `UIActivityViewController`. You can read more about it here:

http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/

Comment: That's a very helpful link you put on there, thank you @KVISH!